# Android wear watchface rotation leaves trail

Tags: java, android, wear-os, watchface

I'm programming a watchface, I put a rotating wheel on the background, but it leaves a strange trail where it has been before and this trail is not deleted. This trail is left only on transparent background area.

Demonstration:

[image]

[image]

```js
final float angle = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2000)
                    / 2000 * 360;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(angle,canvas.getHeight()/2,
canvas.getWidth()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(mWheelBitmap, matrix, new Paint());
invalidate();
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you haven't reset the Matrix. You can reset the matrix like bellow.

```
   matrix.reset();
```

You can follow the bellow code. It worked for me.

```
final float angle = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2000) / 2000 * 360;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.reset();
matrix.setRotate(angle,canvas.getHeight()/2,
canvas.getWidth()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(mWheelBitmap, matrix, new Paint());
invalidate();
```

Its also better practice to initiate the Matrix class inside of onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to clear your `Canvas` before you start drawing the current face:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    // your code starts here
}
```